# Which electrical box to use for old-work outdoor light fixture and vinyl siding mounting block?

Tags: electrical, lighting, outdoor, vinyl-siding

I have a garage which already has vinyl siding on it but the inside is unfinished and accessible. I would like to add an exterior wall lantern.

The vinyl mounting block I purchased looks like this and it is entirely hollow inside (does not contain any sort of structure behind what you see).

[image: vinyl mounting block]

The light fixture I've purchased is just a standard wall lantern with a round base similar to this:

[image: Patriot Lighting Brookline II]

I would like help understanding which electrical junction box is needed behind this and how it should be installed. In order for the light to have any structure holding it up, I believe the junction box will need to be extend past the siding to the front surface of the mounting block. Is this correct? How do I approach this setup?

Comment: Is using a different mounting block an option?

Comment: I think so. I was just trying to avoid taking the siding off

Comment: Can you set your new box next to a stud and use a new construction box having it come flush with the siding? To me that sounds like the solution since you have access. If you want to put it in a space away from a stud scab in some framework to nail to.

Comment: I can probably do that Ed. I'm not sure how to transition it from indoor to outdoor though. Just a small hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a mounting block with a built-in box

The simplest solution to this problem is to use a siding mounting block with a builtin pancake box, such as an [Arlington 8141](https://amzn.to/2LZ5qtd) (the correct part number depends on the lap depth of your siding, the 8141 is what's used with a 1/2" lap) or equivalent.

[image]

Comment: 1/2" D4 siding in my case I think

Comment: I bought a couple of these so I'll see how they work out

Comment: These worked great, by the way